# How can I serve data to front-end in Angular universal App from a server different from ExpressJS server provided by Angular universal?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, server-side-rendering

I am having an issue with  my Angular SSR App that is still in development stage. It's a routing issue. FYI, I am new in Angular (or web dev). The problem is, I can start SSR server and it will work fine if the route on the browser address bar is pointing to static page, that's, a page/component that doesn't fetch data from the backed; I can navigate to any route without any issues. But if I start the SSR server when the link on the browser address bar is pointing to a route that fetches data from the backend, it won't work. The same thing happens when I reload. The browser goes on loading without displaying anything and the terminal shows the error message below  like it's looping until the server crashes.

```
ERROR HttpErrorResponse {
  headers: HttpHeaders {
    normalizedNames: Map {},
    lazyUpdate: null,
    headers: Map {}
  },
  status: 0,
  statusText: 'Unknown Error',
  url: 'http://localhost:4000/http://localhost:3000/api/posts?pagesize=2&page=1
,
  ok: false,
  name: 'HttpErrorResponse',
  message: 'Http failure response for http://localhost:4000/http://localhost:30
0/api/posts?pagesize=2&page=1: 0 Unknown Error',
  error: ProgressEvent {
    type: 'error',
    target: XMLHttpRequest {
      onloadstart: null,
      onprogress: null,
      onabort: null,
      onerror: null,
      onload: null,
      ontimeout: null,
      onloadend: null,
      _listeners: [Object],
      onreadystatechange: null,
      _anonymous: undefined,
      readyState: 4,
      response: null,
      responseText: '',
      responseType: 'text',
      responseURL: '',
      status: 0,
      statusText: '',
      timeout: 0,
      upload: [XMLHttpRequestUpload],
      _method: 'GET',
      _url: [Url],
      _sync: false,
      _headers: [Object],
      _loweredHeaders: [Object],
      _mimeOverride: null,
      _request: null,
      _response: null,
      _responseParts: null,
      _responseHeaders: null,
      _aborting: null,
      _error: null,
      _loadedBytes: 0,
      _totalBytes: 0,
      _lengthComputable: false
    },
......
.....
....
....
    lengthComputable: false,
    loaded: 0,
    total: 0
  }
}

<--- Last few GCs --->

[4452:0000002EB0A8B870]   320685 ms: Mark-sweep 1982.1 (1990.6) -> 1981.2 (1990
6) MB, 1846.0 / 0.2 ms  (average mu = 0.093, current mu = 0.015) allocation fai
ure scavenge might not succeed
[4452:0000002EB0A8B870]   322582 ms: Mark-sweep 1982.1 (1990.6) -> 1981.3 (1990
6) MB, 1785.5 / 0.3 ms  (average mu = 0.077, current mu = 0.059) allocation fai
ure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 00007FF7AB40D31D]
Security context: 0x004c643008d1 <JSObject>
    1: createRenderer [00000150847C9A91] [C:\****\****\Desktop\MEAN STACK\Ng-1
\blog\dist\blog\server\main.js:~1] [pc=000003A6BF0102C6](this=0x02a68959f539 <p
atform_server_ServerRendererFactory2 map = 0000036DB8EC5ED9>,0x012cea722c29 <HT
LButtonElement map = 00000383BFA19079>,0x0298c6e98e51 <Object map = 0000019ACF0
1339>)
    2: addComponentLogic(aka ad...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - Java
cript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF7AA7D286F napi_wrap+119263
 2: 00007FF7AA779536 v8::internal::OrderedHashTable<v8::internal::OrderedHashSe
,1>::NextTableOffset+38102
 3: 00007FF7AA77A336 node::OnFatalError+438
 4: 00007FF7AAFB7B3E v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+94
 5: 00007FF7AAF9FCF1 v8::SharedArrayBuffer::Externalize+833
 6: 00007FF7AAE514CC v8::internal::Heap::EphemeronKeyWriteBarrierFromCode+1436
 7: 00007FF7AAE5C710 v8::internal::Heap::ProtectUnprotectedMemoryChunks+1312
 8: 00007FF7AAE59224 v8::internal::Heap::PageFlagsAreConsistent+3204
 9: 00007FF7AAE4EA23 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage+1283
10: 00007FF7AAE4D094 v8::internal::Heap::AddRetainedMap+2500
11: 00007FF7AAE6E3DD v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject+61
12: 00007FF7AABD19D1 v8::internal::interpreter::JumpTableTargetOffsets::iterato
::operator=+1665
13: 00007FF7AB40D31D v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+546925
14: 000003A6BF0102C6
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 134
npm ERR! blog@0.0.0 serve:ssr: `node dist/blog/server/main.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 134
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the blog@0.0.0 serve:ssr script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional lo
ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Tony\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-08-24T16_40_37_
55Z-debug.log
```

How can I solve this issue? This is my **Angular SSR** below:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

const domino = require('domino');
// const proxyApp = require('./Backend/app');

import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';

// import { createProxyMiddleware } from 'http-proxy-middleware';



// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/blog/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';


  // Shim for the global window and document objects.
  const windowObj = domino.createWindow(indexHtml);
  global.window = windowObj;
  global.document = windowObj.document;
  global.self = windowObj;
  global.IDBIndex = windowObj.IDBIndex;
  global.navigator = windowObj.navigator;
  global.getComputedStyle = windowObj.getComputedStyle;


  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => {
    res.status(404).send('data requests are not yet supported');
  });


  // re-route requests to /api/ to REST api
  // server.use('/api/**', createProxyMiddleware({ target: 'http://localhost:8000', changeOrigin: true }));
  // server.use(proxyApp);



  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));


  // console.log(appRoutes);
  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;


  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

And this is the excerpt from my **NodeJs/ExpressJs** server below:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors'); 
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('./config');



const app = express();
const { db: { URL } } = config;


// const Post = require('./models/post');
const postsRouter = require('./routes/posts');
const userAuthRouter = require('./routes/user');
const adminAuthRouter = require('./routes/admin');
// const commentsRouter = require('./routes/comments');
const topicRouter = require('./routes/topic');


// MongoDB database settings
// Grab mongoDB Authentication password from env. var with obj destructuring and pass it on to mongoose.
const connectionOptions = { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true, /*useFindAndModify: false*/ };
// console.log(URL);
mongoose.connect(URL, connectionOptions )
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Connected Database');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Connection Failed: ' + err);
    });


const whitelist = ['http://localhost:4200', 'http://localhost:4000'];
const corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
      callback(null, true)
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
    }
  }
};


app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true})); // Parse URL-encoded bodies
app.use(express.json());
// app.use(cors())
app.use(cors({ origin: corsOptions }));
app.use(userAuthRouter);
app.use(postsRouter);
app.use(adminAuthRouter);
// app.use(commentsRouter);
app.use(topicRouter);
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join('Backend/images')));


module.exports = app;
```

I am adding additional info. The `postsRouter` and `api/posts` and the route displayed when `ng serve` is used are shown below:

```
//  Get all Posts handler
exports.getPosts = (req, res, next)=> {
    async.parallel({
        posts: function(callback) {
            const pageSize = +req.query.pagesize;
            const currentPage = +req.query.page;
            const topic = req.query.topic;
            // Get All Posts
            if (pageSize && currentPage && topic) {
                Post.find({'topic': topic})
                    .skip(pageSize * (currentPage - 1))
                    .limit(pageSize)
                    .sort({publishDate: 'desc'})
                    .exec(callback);
            }
            // Group Post Based On Topic
            if (pageSize && currentPage && !topic) {
                // console.log(topic + " : " + id + ' 2nd');
                Post.find({}, ' -topicID')
                    .skip(pageSize * (currentPage - 1))
                    .limit(pageSize)
                    .sort({publishDate: 'desc'})
                    .exec(callback);
            }
        },
        postCount: function(callback) {
            Post.countDocuments(callback);
        }
    },
    function(err, results) {
        if (err) {  
            return res.status(500).json({message: 'ERROR: Fetching Posts Failed!'});
         }
        res.status(200).json({
            posts: results.posts,
            postCount: results.postCount,
            });
        });
};
```

```
// Post service: Angular

 getPosts(groupedPostTopic = '', postsPerPage?: number, currentPage?: number): void {
    // Backend Params for pagination
    const placeHolder = groupedPostTopic ? `/posts?topic=${groupedPostTopic}&` : '/posts?';
    const queryParam = `pagesize=${postsPerPage}&page=${currentPage}`;
    // Call to the server
    const posts$ = this.http.get<{posts: Post[], postCount: number}>(BACKEND_URL + placeHolder + queryParam)
    .pipe(map((postData) => {
      return { posts: postData.posts.map((post: any) => {
        const textStyle = this.dateTextStyle(post.publishDate);
        return {
                id: post._id,
                topic: post.topic,
                title: post.title,
                postIntro: post.postIntro,
                content: post.content,
                imagePath: post.imagePath,
                dateTextStyle: textStyle,
                publishDate: post.publishDate,
                creator: post.creator,
                comments: post.comments
              };
        }),
        postCount: postData.postCount
      };
    }));
    // Activate spinner service until data arrival
    this.isLoadingService.showContentUntilCompleted(posts$)
    .subscribe(transformedPosts => {
      this.posts = transformedPosts.posts;
      this.postCount = transformedPosts.postCount;
      // Data stored to be Observed using BehaviorSubject and/or asObservable() from rsjx
      this.subject.next({posts: [...this.posts], postCount: transformedPosts.postCount});
    });

  }
```

```
// Displayed route when 'ng serve' is used
http://localhost:4200/posts
***OR***
http://localhost:4200/posts/:pageNo // For pagination
```

***Thanks in advance!***

Comment: Look at the ```url``` field in the error response ```http://localhost:4000/http://localhost:3000/api/posts?pagesize=2&page=1```. How do you call this url in your angular app?  Does the app work with ```ng serve``` ?

Comment: @Lukasz Gawrys Thanks for responding. The Angular Universal server runs on port 4000 while the server that serves actual data to the client runs on port 3000. When ***ng serve*** is used it works fine. Do you know how I can resolve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Can you also show code of your service in angular which triggers the http call to ```api/posts``` and also code of ```postsRouter``` in node.js?

Comment: And if you run ```ng serve``` how does the url for api call look like?

Comment: @Lukasz Gawrys Hi! I really appreciate the help. I am sorry for replying a little late. I have added more info as you request.

Comment: @Lukasz Gawrys Hi! I have discovered the cause of the url error response. It's the ```HttpInterceptor``` I am using to intercept request for SSR .